# How to display value in formula field using logged in user locale?

Tags: formula-field

Use case,
I want to display value of Invoice Date on Quote Template document based on logged in user locale.

We have date field in `Line Columns` of CPQ Quote template where we add API Name of date field , which we are using to display value on Quote Template.

Now this date field I want to display value based on logged in user locale, can anyone advise how we can do this using formula field.

e.g on visual-force page we do like

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,short}">
     <apex:param value="{!obj.InviceDate}"/>   
</apex:outputText>
```

How to achieve same thing using SF formula field.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5) about "Using Date, Date/Time, and Time Values in Formulas"  :

> Date, Date/Time, and Time fields are formatted in the user’s locale when viewed in reports and record detail pages.

So if you create a formula field of type Date and reference the Invoice Date, this will normally display the date as per logged in user's locale.

can you try it and see if this works on the document template ?